# How do I correctly set the middleware for protecting the dynamic path that is the root of the application using next auth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware, next-auth

I am using the `next-auth` package for authentication on my application. I have been able to protect other routes and even other dynamic ones using the middleware.ts file but I am having problems using the middleware for the root dynamic urls that is in this format: `/[slug]/home`, `/[slug]/workspace`, `/[slug]/members`.

When I added this line: `/:path*` to the matchers array, it correctly detected that I was not authenticated but on redirecting me to the signin page, I got the error `Try deleting your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` because the redirections were too much.

Here is my middleware.ts file:

```
export { default } from 'next-auth/middleware';

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/',
    '/ws/:path*',
    '/onboarding',
    '/board/invite',
    '/verify/:token',
    '/:path*',
  ]
};
```

How do I fix the error and get it to work

I have tried different variations of the middleware but none seemed to work.

Here is one of those variations:

```
export { default } from 'next-auth/middleware';

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/',
    '/:path*',
    '/ws/:path*',
    '/onboarding',
    '/board/invite',
    '/verify/:token',
  ]
};
```

I also manually added a check to all the routes under `/[slug]` using the getServerSession method but it's not as efficient as the middleware and also doesn't add a callback url.

Comment: I have this problem too. In my case is username, for example: '/@elonmusk/:path*'. I don't know the work around with it.